# Manipulate works if I put an expression in but not if I abstract that away

Tags: manipulate

This gives an error:

```
myline=Line[{{g, 0}, {10, 10}}]
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{myline}, Axes -> True], {g, 0, 10}]
```

But this works:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line[{{g, 0}, {10, 10}}]}, Axes -> True], {g, 0, 10}]
```

Why?

I hope to get the former to work because I have very long/large expressions so the latter is a very long unreadable line.

== EDIT: ==

Syed gave a good answer. And it works for more than one variable, like

```
myline=Line[{{g, h}, {10, 10}}]
```

However I can't get it to work when one of the variables is a 2d {x,y} point! So for example this doesn't work:

```
myline = Line[{pt, pt + {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}]
With[{myline = myline}, 
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[{myline}, PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True], {t, 0 Degree, 
   90 Degree}, {{pt, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]]
```

But this does:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line[{pt, pt + {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}]}, PlotRange -> 1, 
  Axes -> True], {t, 0 Degree, 
  90 Degree}, {{pt, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]
```

Here t is theta (angle) and pt is an {x,y} point as you can see.
I've tried putting t and pt inside the With, like this:

```
With[{myline = myline, t = t, pt = pt}, ...
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: In the first version that does not work, add `g=0` as the first statement.

Comment: That indeed gets rid of the error. But 'g' is no longer manipulable. If you slide the g slider, the plot doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work better.

```
myline = Line[{{g, 0}, {10, 10}}]
With[{myline = myline},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[{myline}
   , PlotRange -> {{-1, 10}, {1, 10}}
   , Axes -> True]
  , {g, 0, 10}
  ]
 ]
```

---

**EDIT to accomodate the new variation by the OP**

```
Clear[myline];
myline[pt_, t_] := Line[{pt, pt + {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}]

With[{ pt = pt, t = t},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[{myline[pt, t]},
   PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True],
  {t, 0 Degree, 90 Degree},
  {{pt, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}
  ]
 ]
```

---

**EDIT** after MarcoB's comment:

With is no longer required. (Thanks @MarcoB)

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{myline[pt, t]},
  PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True],
 {t, 0 Degree, 90 Degree},
 {{pt, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}
 ]
```

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to work when you make the following two changes: myline=Line[{pt, pt + {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}}] AND instead of g's range you use {{\[Theta], \[Pi]/2}, 0 , \[Pi]}, {{pt, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}

Comment: Sorry for the formatting issue above. Basically where there was one parameter (g) before, I'm adding in two parameters now (theta and pt; "pt" is an {x,y} point) that defines one point on the line. In general I'm struggling to get this to work when one of the parameters is a 2d {x,y} point.

Comment: What is `Sin[[Theta]]` ? I don't think this can be a valid part spec. The idea is to make variables available inside `Manipulate` as other answers have pointed out as well. Try to fix the syntax and add variables inside the `With` braces.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the question with what I was trying to describe. Please see the edited question?

Comment: thanks for your edit. I copied and pasted that in to my Mma (v12.0) and it gave me the error: "Manipulate argument {{{-1.,-1.},{0,0}},{-1,-1},{1,1}} does not have the correct form for a variable specification."

Comment: Oops, never mind! It works, I just had to clear all other variables. Marking your answer as correct now!

Comment: @Syed in your edited version, why do you need the `With` construct? The dependence of myline on pt and t is made explicit to Manipulate and it works fine without. The critical part was always to make the variable dependence explicit within manipulate, and defining myline as a function accomplished that.

Answer (score 5):

Make g "known" within Manipulate

```
myline[g_] = Line[{{g, 0}, {10, 10}}]
Manipulate[Graphics[{myline[g]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 10}, {1, 10}}
 , Axes -> True], {g, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: This works for g, and if I add another variable like h.  However I can't get it to work if one of those variables is an {x,y} pair, as I described in the edit to the question above. Any thoughts?

Comment: @dnh234589 The analog to Akku14's solution for two parameters would be `myline[pt_, t_] := Line[{pt, pt + {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}]'` -- Did you try that? (Ah, probably you used `=` instead of `:=`, which is important here, but not in Akku14's answer.  The reason is that `pt + {Cos[t], Sin[t]}` evaluates to `{pt + Cos[t], pt + Sin[t]}` before `pt` is assigned a value as a pair of coordinates.)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `LocalizeVariables -> False`. but I do not think this is the best way to write your code. But this minimizes the changes you have to do

```
myline = Line[{{g, 0}, {10, 10}}]
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{myline}, Axes -> True],
 {g, 0, 10},
 TrackedSymbols :> {g},
 LocalizeVariables -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is that `g` symbol did not appear in the Manipulate expression (i.e.) inside Manipulate.  This option tells Manipulate to look outside (in the global space). But it is risky to do this.

And you should always use `TrackedSymbols` in any choice you pick.

Comment: Yeah, this works for 'g', and I can add other variables such as 'h'. However, if one of those variables is an {x,y} pair as I showed in the edit to the question above, I can't get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nasser Hi, Nasser, your code does not work for me (Win10, Mma 12.0). Does it depend on the version?

Comment: @Alexei, it works for me and I'm using Win10 Mma 12.0. I just copied and pasted as-is and it works. Check again?

Comment: @dnh234589 Thank you. From your previous comment, I have already understood that it works for you, but for me, it does not. For me it only starts working as soon as I define myline as a function of g. That is, `myline[g_] := Line[{{g, 0}, {10, 10}}];`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch  it works for me on 12.3.1.  I do not know why it would not work in 12.0. This seems strange. It runs OK also. I just tried in on 12.0 and you are correct. For some reason it comes up but it does not respond to slider change. I assume this is a bug in V 12.0 and has been fixed since.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you. It is good to know.