# Drag around a bunch of graphics

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to draw several lines, and be able to drag around these lines all together, using a `Locator`. So they will all translate together when the Locator is dragged.

I posted [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259642/manipulate-works-if-i-put-an-expression-in-but-not-if-i-abstract-that-away) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/260902/passing-a-list-reference-to-manipulate-has-a-different-effect-to-passing-the-lis). The first one was answered; in the second one it was suggested I start a new post with exactly what I'm trying to do. Here goes!

Below is my attempt. Basically I add a 2d point called "pt" to each x and y, and then add a `Locator` to `pt`.

If I write `pt={0,0}` at the start, manipulate doesn't seem to be able to change its value (you drag the Locator and nothing moves). If I DON'T initialize `pt` at the start, then Mma thinks pt is a scalar and adds this "scalar" to both x and y, which means yes I can drag it now, but the line vertices are drawn incorrectly (you see diagonal lines instead of two vertical lines). Below is the former case; for the latter case just delete the `pt={0,0}`.

```
Clear["`*"]
P = {};
pt = {0, 0}
p1[w_, h_] := {-w, -h};
p2[w_, h_] := {-w, h};
p3[w_, h_] := {w, -h};
p4[w_, h_] := {w, h};
line1[w_, h_, pt_] := Line[{p1[w, h] + pt, p2[w, h] + pt}];
line2[w_, h_, pt_] := Line[{p3[w, h] + pt, p4[w, h] + pt}];
AppendTo[P, line1[w, h, pt]];
AppendTo[P, line2[w, h, pt]];
With[{P = P}, 
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[P, PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True], {{w, 0.5}, 0, 
   1}, {{h, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{pt, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Locator}]]
```

Note: If you want to see the EXPECTED behavior, replace `Graphics[P` with `Graphics[{line1[w,h,pt],line2[w,h,pt]}`. However I can't use this because I have a LOT of lines and pasting them verbatim inside `Graphics` doesn't seem like a great solution.

Comment: check what `P` holds after each `AppendTo[P...]`  (that is, use `AppendTo[P,...];P`) to see what is happening.

Comment: a simpler way to define `P` is `P ={line1[w,h,pt], line2[w,h,pt]}`.

Comment: Yes. If I print (i.e. Echo) P, and if I print {line1[w,h,pt], line2[w,h,pt]} I get the exact same thing. Problem is, if I initialize pt={0,0} then yeah it's 2d so it gets added as a vector not scalar, BUT I can't seem to get Locate to work. If I don't initialize pt then it thinks it's a scalar. In both cases, P is built correctly, so I don't think that is the problem. The problem is, I need a way for Mma to know that pt is a 2d list (so it does the math correctly), without initializing it (so that Locate works correctly).

Comment: Here is a simpler working version of your code: `Manipulate[
 Graphics[{line1[w, h, pt], line2[w, h, pt]}, PlotRange -> 1, 
  Axes -> True]
 , {{w, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{h, 0.5}, 0, 
  1}, {{pt, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Locator}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more streamlined approach:

```
ClearAll[Q, w, h, pt]

Q = Translate[Line @ Partition[Tuples[{{-w, w}, {-h, h}}], 2], pt];

With[{Q = Q}, 
 Manipulate[Graphics[Q, PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True], 
  {{w, 0.5}, 0, 1},
  {{h, 0.5}, 0, 1},
  {{pt, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Locator}]]
```

With minimal changes to your code:

```
ClearAll[P, p1, p2, p3, p4, pt, w, h, line1, line2]
p1[w_, h_] := {-w, -h};
p2[w_, h_] := {-w, h};
p3[w_, h_] := {w, -h};
p4[w_, h_] := {w, h};

line1[w_, h_, pt : {_, _}] := Line[{p1[w, h] + pt, p2[w, h] + pt}];
line2[w_, h_, pt : {_, _}] := Line[{p3[w, h] + pt, p4[w, h] + pt}];

P = {line1[w, h, pt], line2[w, h, pt]};

With[{P = P}, 
 Manipulate[Graphics[P, PlotRange -> 1, Axes -> True],
  {{w, 0.5}, 0, 1},
  {{h, 0.5}, 0, 1},
  {{pt, {0, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, Locator}]]
```

both methods give:

[image]

Comment: pt : {_, _} was what I needed! I didn't even know of that syntax! Thanks SO much!

Comment: @dnh234589, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: I'm trying to find info online about that colon and underscore syntax. A quick search turns up several different uses of colon and underscore (like underscores in variable names, underscores after variable names, double underscores). Anyway can you please tell me what this is called so I can search for and read about it?

Comment: see  [Pattern (:)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) in the docs. (a quick way to get to the relevant documentation page for any mysterious object is to highlight it and hit F1)

Comment: see also [Blank (_)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)